# Create a table with first seen pages by user instead cookies. Is a bad practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, cookies

I'm trying to avoid client side cookies because of different browsers to show again tour around pages in my app.

The user only have to see the tour when he firsts saw it. Then I'm thinking in a table like this:

**table:** users x pages_that_viewed

```
user_id      seen_page         seen_profile        seen_another_page...

  12         2012-12-12 

  13         2012-12-12         2012-12-12
```

Then I will have to join the table users with this one every time...

Another solution then will be adding this columns directly to users table.

Comment: Why you don't want to use cookies?

Comment: sorry, does this tour is different in every page of your app?

Comment: yes, each page has its own tour

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how many pages you have and how many pages you are planning on adding, each additional page will require a database schema modification. Generally speaking, it's not a good idea. You can create one record per user per page instead. Index on user_id, page_id. If you want to know when they accessed it, third field would be date, otherwise a boolean will do. Another alternative is to use bitmap, but that will not work if you need dates, however it will only take 1 record per page to keep track of all user visits.

Bitmap field would store something like this 001000100011110010 where each digit represents a user_id and stores a visit to that page. Ex. user_id 12, would be the 12th digit 0 or 1 etc. On a visit you would update 1 field and set Nth digit to 1. Bitmaps are generally very fast and support some additional operations like unions, intersections etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think a column would be more cost effective, much less queries...

try a boolean tour column then when someone logs to your app just fetch the column and store it in a session

```
session[:tour] ||= @user.tour
```

Comment: You can get all visited pages for a user in one query, and assign it to session variable, or get one page only. It scales to 1,000,000 pages while having columns might not, some databases will not allow that many fields or row length.

Comment: yeah i asked him if each of his pages had a tour, at first i thought it was the same tour for every page. i might have to edit this when he answers

Answer (score 0):

after reading your last comment i came up with this idea, I think you should make a relation between users and pages that would be a many to many asociation, then you could have a junction table pages_users with columns user_id and page_id, then at each render check if the current user has the current page. i think that is the best way to go.